# Sort() is mutating my original array. Is there a different workaround?

Tags: javascript

I've searched other threads and I couldn't find a working solution to my problem. I tried slice() for the array but no luck. I've got a array, first I create a copy of the original array and after a few second I overwrite one value [0][1]=555. And this affects my copy/original array, the value 1000 gets overwritten with 555. Any ideas on how to overcome this? I need to compare the two tables after the value gets changed. Here is my javascript code:

```
let intialstationtablevalues = [
["station name 1",75,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,100,1],
["station name 2",200,220,100,100,100,100,100,2,100,100,100,100,2],
["station name 3",300,110,100,100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,760,3],
["station name 4",400,100,109,100,100,100,100,3,100,100,100,100,4],
["station name 5",500,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,100,5],
["station name 6",600,130,134,100,100,100,100,2,100,100,100,340,6],
["station name 7",700,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,100,7],
["station name 8",800,200,340,100,100,100,100,5,100,100,100,10,8],
["station name 9",900,100,100,100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,6,9],
["station name 10",1000,100,900,100,100,100,100,2,100,100,100,100,10],
];
let old = []
let copy = []


setInterval(read,2000)
setTimeout(changevalue,10000)

function changevalue(){
  console.log("value changed")
  intialstationtablevalues[0][1]=555;
}


function read(){
        if(copy==""){
            copy = intialstationtablevalues.slice()
      }
        sortnow = intialstationtablevalues.sort(function(a,b){
            return b[1]-a[1];
        })

        console.log("sortnow",sortnow)

        if(old==""){
            copy.forEach(function(item,index){
                old.push(item)
            })
            old.sort(function(a,b){
                return b[1]-a[1];
            })
        }

        console.log("old",old)
}
```

Comment: You make a copy with `.slice()` but then you proceed to sort the original array anyway. The `.sort()` method sorts the array for which it's invoked.

Comment: `.slice` is the correct solution but you've fallen into shallow vs deep copy confusion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: `if(copy=="")` - That's not how you should test for an empty array. It works but only because JavaScript has truthy/falsy values.

Comment: Aluan Haddad so is there a way of doing this right to get what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortedArray = [...arrayYouWantToSort].sort()` Spreading the array you want to copy into a new array and then sort that array. Fun way to do it!

```
sortedArray = [...arrayYouWantToSort];
sortedArray[0][1] = whatever // whatever you wanna change
sortedArray.sort()
```

The main point is that spreading the `arrayYouWantToSort` into a new array literal creates a new array in memory. So `arrayYouWantToSort` and `sortedArray` are now total different physical parts of memory, but they have the same 'values'. So you can change values in one without affecting the other.

So you first create the copied array, and then mutate the new array.

Comment: Ah didn't read the whole thing sorry. Still just use the spread operator. Ill update my response

Comment: Well I think I've done it correctly if(copy.length===0){
   copy = [...intialstationtablevalues]
   }

Comment: should do it. And then use the copy

Comment: it still throws the 555 value in the copy array or maybe I'm doing somethind wrong...;)

Comment: Hmm. The only way that could happen is either intialStationableValues has 555 set before you spread, or you set it after. What is the point of this function exactly?

Comment: well this is just a small fragment of a bigger project that I'm working on. I'm working with dynamically changing value and I need to compare coming in new values with the old ones, and based on that make suitable actions. ...I gave the change 555 value a timeout of 10seconds just to make sure

Comment: is it possible for you to copy the code and console.log it in your browser to check if it's only me getting this effect ? ;)

Comment: OK. I found a solution. copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(intialstationtablevalues))

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023 [.toSorted()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) can be used to return sorted array without mutating original array

Answer (score -1):

I think .slice() is working fine here, try to replace the if statment with

```
if(copy.length ===0)
```

to check the empty array

Comment: I'm still getting the same 555 result in the copy array